# How to convert Excel XLS to CSV using PHP

Tags: php, csv, xls

Can anyone guide me how to convert XLS to CSV using PHP?

I have excel spread sheet which contains a list of documents, I want to convert this with CSV format using PHP.

Comment: Excel has a CSV export option. Is it not feasible to have your users use that? (Just thinking of the least work-intensive way...)

Comment: A CSV file can only contain one table of data, so it's not possible to convert one XLS file with multiple tables into one CSV file.

Comment: Sure you can, and it's a worksheet you refer to.  it will export the last worksheet by default.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Probably you can start [reading a XLS using PHP](http://www.ustrem.org/en/articles/reading-xls-with-php-en/).

Then, using the main logic to output what you want (csv in your case).

Good luck,

Answer (score 22):

Rewrite the code provided by @Rajat Modi using PhpSpreadsheet library due to PHPExcel is deprecated.

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet

https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/

```
<?php 

require 'vendor\autoload.php';

use \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx;
use \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Csv;

$xls_file = "Example.xlsx";

$reader = new Xlsx();
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($xls_file);

$loadedSheetNames = $spreadsheet->getSheetNames();

$writer = new Csv($spreadsheet);

foreach($loadedSheetNames as $sheetIndex => $loadedSheetName) {
    $writer->setSheetIndex($sheetIndex);
    $writer->save($loadedSheetName.'.csv');
}
```

Comment: I got "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx' ", any idea why?

Comment: Did you include require 'vendor\autoload.php';

Comment: //Changed to
$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
$writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Csv($spreadsheet);

//add BOM to anable UTF-8
$writer->setUseBOM(true);

Answer (score 21):

This will surely work,

```
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$inputFileType = 'Excel5';
$inputFileName = 'YOUR_EXCEL_FILE_PATH';

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcelReader = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

$loadedSheetNames = $objPHPExcelReader->getSheetNames();

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcelReader, 'CSV');

foreach($loadedSheetNames as $sheetIndex => $loadedSheetName) {
    $objWriter->setSheetIndex($sheetIndex);
    $objWriter->save($loadedSheetName.'.csv');
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: You don't even give a link to where to get IOFactory!

Comment: Perfect. thanks Rajat.
Considering, you have several tabs in an xls/xlsx sheet, how would you convert all or a specific tab, with 1 csv file for each tab?

Comment: how to set export.csv save path

Comment: 2007 above not converting into csv

Comment: PHPExcel is now deprecated: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41118123/1043704

Answer (score 6):

You can use the php library [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) to read the excel file, and just loop over the rows and cells and just write the data out to a csv file?

Comment: It's now "PHPSpreadsheet". I managed to find these details about how to read and write from / to a file: https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-and-writing-to-file/

Answer (score 2):

This will work. [Install Spout](https://opensource.box.com/spout/docs/)

```
<?php 
require 'vendor\autoload.php';
use Box\Spout\Writer\Common\Creator\WriterEntityFactory;
use Box\Spout\Reader\Common\Creator\ReaderEntityFactory;

$writer = WriterEntityFactory::createCSVWriter();
$reader = ReaderEntityFactory::createXLSXReader();
$writer->openToFile("Output CSV path");
$reader->open("Input XSLX path");

foreach ($reader->getSheetIterator() as $sheet) {
   foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
       $writer->addRow($row);
   }
}

$writer->close();
$reader->close();
```