# convert an EXCEL file to CSV file in PHP

Tags: php, csv, import-from-excel

I want to convert Excel files (.xls) into CSV file (.csv) with a script PHP ?
I tried many codes but it didn't work like this one !
No errors appear but it wont work Any idea or any other lines of codes that I can try ?

```
<?php

echo("it works");
require_once '../batchs/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$inputFileType = 'Excel5';
$inputFileName = '../public/aixstream/stock.xls';

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcelReader = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

$loadedSheetNames = $objPHPExcelReader->getSheetNames();

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcelReader, 'CSV');

foreach($loadedSheetNames as $sheetIndex => $loadedSheetName) {
    $objWriter->setSheetIndex($sheetIndex);
    $objWriter->save($loadedSheetName.'.csv');
}
?>
```

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766317/how-to-convert-excel-xls-to-csv-using-php

Comment: can you try changing $objWriter->save($loadedSheetName.'.csv'); to $objWriter->save('./'.$loadedSheetName.'.csv'); and see if it works

Comment: I changed it but it didn't work !

Comment: check in javascript console , is it showing any error

Comment: Nope ther's no errors at all !

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7766358) answer, you can use the `PHP-ExcelReader` [function](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/files/) to read the `xls` file. After that, you may easily convert it into CSV (or any other other format) using the following code, also available [here](http://www.ustrem.org/en/articles/reading-xls-with-php-en/).

**Reading the xls file**

```
//You will obviously need to import the function
//by downloading the file from the link above.

$reader=new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader(); //Instantiate the function
$reader->setUTFEncoder('iconv'); // Set Encoder
$reader->setOutputEncoding('UTF-8'); // Set Output Encoding Type
$reader->read($filename); // Read the xls file
```

**Data Output**

```
/***
* Information about sheets is stored in boundsheets variable.
* This code displays each sheet's name.
***/
foreach ($reader->boundsheets as $k=>$sheet) //Run loop for all sheets in the file
 {
    echo "\n$k: $sheet"; 
 }

//Now just save the data in the array as csv

/***
* Data of the sheets is stored in sheets variable.
* For every sheet, a two dimensional array holding table is created.
* This code saves all data to CSV file.
***/
 foreach($reader->sheets as $k=>$data) // Run loop for all items.
 {
    echo "\n\n ".$reader->boundsheets[$k]."\n\n"; //Print Title

    foreach($data['cells'] as $row) // Loop for all items
    {
        foreach($row as $cell) // Loop for every cell
        {
            echo "$cell".","; //Add a comma after each value
        }
    }
 }

//It works! :D
```

Comment: Can you please explain to me the code ? you will find my answer and the code below because it's too long for a comment

Comment: Yes, your code below seems just fine when I look at it, though I have not checked by running it. Have you tried running it? Don't forget, you need to include the function I gave a link to in the answer for this to work.

I have edited my answer to include comments explaining how the code works. The detailed explanation, as I already stated, is also available [in this link](http://www.ustrem.org/en/articles/reading-xls-with-php-en/).