# How to include phpspreadsheet library without composer?

Tags: php, composer-php, phpspreadsheet

There isn't a way for me to run composer on my server for a bunch of reasons. Is there any way to include all the files necessary to use the library?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use PhpSpreadsheet without installation (like PHPExcel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48767355/how-to-use-phpspreadsheet-without-installation-like-phpexcel)

Comment: you dont need to (and indeed you shouldn't). run composer locally, and just transfer the files to your server.

Comment: @delboy1978uk I did copy the phpspreadsheet files (the whole directory) to the server. Is there any way to load classes, without having to include one by one?

Comment: you either require every class (the way you just uploaded), just install composer locally, `composer require yourvendor/package`, `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php` in your script, and you can now autoload everything without requires. Just upload the composer.json, composer.lock, and vendor folders and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I have `phpspreadsheet` in (from the root html folder)

`lib/php/phpspreadsheet`

I just

`require_once( 'lib/php/phpspreadsheet/autoload.php' );`

then (since I am inside an already defined namespace) I create a spreadsheet with

`$spreadsheet = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();`

Answer (score -2):

@Lubosdz answered the question in the right way here:

[How to use PhpSpreadsheet without installation (like PHPExcel)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48767355)

Just coping files isn't enaugh to get it worked because composer is used to autoload all PhpSpreadSheet classes.

Without composer, you have to create your custom ones.

You can find a 4 steps method, files, and code here:

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/31#issuecomment-354502740

Comment: Please include all relevant information here instead of linking to external pages

Answer (score -2):

## 07 2021

If any of you still looking for the solution. Then here it is.

### How to run PhpSpreadsheet on a Server without Composer

See @delboy1978uk comment above

### Run PhpSpreadsheet locally without Composer

Official:

> Composer is the only official and supported solution to use
> PhpSpreadsheet. Alternative custom solutions are possible, but I'd
> strongly advise against them. Not using composer will give you more
> work to set up, and potential issues to maintain.
>
> https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/discussions/1969#discussioncomment-545159

Answer (score -2):

As @delboy1978uk stated in the answer above:

- Run composer local on your machine,
- create the composer.json,
- require phpspreadsheet (https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet)
- composer update
- upload the complete /vendor Folder on your server,
  maybe as zip it is easier,
- include /vendor/autoload.php,
- there it is

And send a Sixpack of your favorite Beer to Mark Baker https://github.com/MarkBaker for his great work :-)