# Failed to upload an Excel file

Tags: php, excel, upload, phpexcel

I made an excel file using the phpexcel library, and when I tried to upload the file, it was not uploaded.

The strange thing is that when I open the created Excel file, save it, and upload it again, the file size increases and I can upload it.

Why is this?

I don't want to open and save the excel file every time.
Because thousands of hundreds of excel files are created.

If anyone has any advice, please.

Comment: Please fix your question's title

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How should I fix it? I'm new to this website.

Comment: `Failed to upload an Excel file` is good enough

Comment: Oh I really appreciate your advice! I fixed it! 

Comment: Welcome. I would suggest you read this post as you may have more luck using a newer package : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117762/what-are-the-main-differences-between-phpexcel-and-phpspreadsheet

Comment: Thanks for the comment!! I will try next Monday! I hope it work for me!! 