# float percent PHPExcel_IOFactory

Tags: php, csv, phpexcel, export-to-csv

[I've seen this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20041261) and it's work. But the percent is not converted.

Ex : 
In the xls, C1 = 0,0226115615112098%
After the convertion, in the CSV, C1 = ?0.2f%

I don't find how specify the good format in this case.

[image]

The post example is :

```
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$inputFileType = 'Excel5';
$inputFileName = 'YOUR_EXCEL_FILE_PATH';

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcelReader = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

$loadedSheetNames = $objPHPExcelReader->getSheetNames();

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcelReader, 'CSV');

foreach($loadedSheetNames as $sheetIndex => $loadedSheetName) {
    $objWriter->setSheetIndex($sheetIndex);
    $objWriter->save($loadedSheetName.'.csv');
}
```

[Link to the library](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)

Comment: Hello. Can you add a sample of your code ?

Comment: So what is the code that you're using to do this conversion?

Comment: I've post the link with the code. It's all. I add it if you want