# Will PHPSpreadsheet convert xls to xlsx and preserve formatting?

Tags: phpspreadsheet

I am on the fact-finding part of our project specs and have not found a definitive answer re whether PHPSpreadsheet can convert an `.xls` to `.xlsx` *and preserve formatting, such as table borders.*

[From this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766317/how-to-convert-excel-xls-to-csv-using-php), I see that there are separate imports for read/write and for file format type. This example demonstrates use of the different modules for read/write file formats:

```
<?php 

require 'vendor\autoload.php';

use \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xls;
use \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$xls_file = "Example.xls";

$reader = new Xls();
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($xls_file);

$loadedSheetNames = $spreadsheet->getSheetNames();

$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);

foreach($loadedSheetNames as $sheetIndex => $loadedSheetName) {
    $writer->setSheetIndex($sheetIndex);
    $writer->save($loadedSheetName.'.xlsx');
}
```

However, I have not seen if the resultant export preserves formatting, specifically border lines. At the moment, I am unable to write this myself.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested PhpSpreadsheet *(due to Composer requirement),* but FWIW PhpExcel *(the predecessor to PhpSpreadsheet)* does the job quite handily ***and*** yes, it does preserve most formatting.

Here is a sample conversion script using PhpExcel:

```
<?php

    $xls_to_convert = 'test.xls';

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

    define('EOL',(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');

    date_default_timezone_set('America/Vancouver');

    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load(dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . $xls_to_convert);

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save(str_replace('.xls', '.xlsx', $xls_to_convert));
```

A cursory comparison of my test `xls` spreadsheet against the `xlsx` result shows:

1. font sizes, font colors, bold/italic, borders, centering, cell background/shading/colors, drop-downs with values, are preserved
2. Buttons are lost
3. Shapes (e.g. lines, arrows, textboxes) are lost
4. Charts are lost